# How to save and reload a Subclassed model in TF 2.6.0 / Python 3.9.7 wihtout performance drop?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Looks like the million dollars question. I have the model below built by sub classing `Model` in Keras.

Model trains fine and have good performance but I cannot find a way to save and restore the model without incurring a significant performance loss.
I track AUC on ROC curves for anomaly detection, and the ROC curve after loading the model is worse than before, using exactly the same validation data set.

I suspect the problem to come from the BatchNormalization, but I could be wrong.

I've tried several option:

This works but leads to performance drop.

```
model.save() / tf.keras.models.load()
```

This works but also lead to performance drop:

```
model.save_weights() / model.load_weights()
```

This does not work and I get the following error:

```
tf.saved_model.save() / tf.saved_model.load()

AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

This does not work either, as Subclassed model do not support json export:

```
model.to_json()
```

**Here is the model**:

```
class Deep_Seq2Seq_Detector(Model):
  def __init__(self, flight_len, param_len, hidden_state=16):
    super(Deep_Seq2Seq_Detector, self).__init__()
    self.input_dim = (None, flight_len, param_len)
    self._name_ = "LSTM"
    self.units = hidden_state
    
    self.regularizer0 = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.BatchNormalization()
        ])
    
    self.encoder1 = layers.LSTM(self.units,
                  return_state=False,
                  return_sequences=True,
                  #activation="tanh",
                  name='encoder1',
                  input_shape=self.input_dim)#,
                  #kernel_regularizer= tf.keras.regularizers.l1(),
                  #)
    
    self.regularizer1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.BatchNormalization(),
        layers.Activation("tanh")
        ])
    
    self.encoder2 = layers.LSTM(self.units,
                  return_state=False,
                  return_sequences=True,
                  #activation="tanh",
                  name='encoder2')#,
                  #kernel_regularizer= tf.keras.regularizers.l1()
                  #) #                    input_shape=(None, self.input_dim[1],self.units),
    
    self.regularizer2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
        layers.BatchNormalization(),
        layers.Activation("tanh")
        ])
    
    self.encoder3 = layers.LSTM(self.units,
                  return_state=True,
                  return_sequences=False,
                  activation="tanh",
                  name='encoder3')#,
                  #kernel_regularizer= tf.keras.regularizers.l1(),
                  #) #                   input_shape=(None, self.input_dim[1],self.units),
    
    self.repeat = layers.RepeatVector(self.input_dim[1])
    
    self.decoder = layers.LSTM(self.units,
                  return_sequences=True,
                  activation="tanh",
                  name="decoder",
                  input_shape=(self.input_dim[1],self.units))
    
    self.dense = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(self.input_dim[2]))

  @tf.function 
  def call(self, x):
    
    # Encoder
    x0 = self.regularizer0(x)
    x1 = self.encoder1(x0)
    x11 = self.regularizer1(x1)
    
    x2 = self.encoder2(x11)
    x22 = self.regularizer2(x2)
    
    output, hs, cs = self.encoder3(x22)
    
    # see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn 
    encoded_state = [hs, cs] 
    repeated_vec = self.repeat(output)
    
    # Decoder
    decoded = self.decoder(repeated_vec, initial_state=encoded_state)
    output_decoder = self.dense(decoded)

    return output_decoder
```

I've seen Git threads, but no straight answer:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875

Did anyone found a solution ? Do I have to use the Functional or Sequential API instead ?

Comment: Please share reproducible code with some dummy data.

Comment: @M.Innat, thanks, unfortunately I fear giving dummy data won't be of any help. My problem is that the model performance drop. You won't be able to observe these drop using dummy data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was coming from the `Sublcassing API`.

I reconstructed the exact same model using the `Functionnal API` and now `model.save` / `model.load` yields similar results.